# How do I blur an image using Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image

[image]

which is basically converted from some original good image to the above shown first image.

I want to apply the same effect(as shown in above image) to this image

[image]

I have installed Photoshop CS 6. How to do this?

Comment: FYI, if you are trying to blur the image enough to "bypass" a copyright, that wont work, as it is considered a derivative work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489914/photoshop-how-to-apply-effect-on-original-image dont cross post at so sites,doesnt the answer provided there is not helpfull?This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graphicdesign.stackexchange.com will be good option for u

Comment: @Vignesh4303 okay i  got it, actually i do not know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Gaussian blur filter. Go to Filter → Blur  → Gaussian Blur